# Setting the background colour of zebra-striped table rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html-table, pseudo-element

I am using:

```
tr:nth-child(2n+1) {
  background-color: #DDDDDD;
}
```

To zebra-stripe a table. I have the class:

```
.redbg {
  background-color: #FF6666;
}
```

And am using:

```
$(this).parent().parent().addClass("redbg");
```

To use JQuery to change the background colour of the rows when I need to.

Unfortunatly, it only works on the non-2n+1 rows. How do I recolour the #DDDDDD rows?

Comment: Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SXB3e/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply change the "redbg" class to add the tr to the front:

```
tr.redbg {
    background-color: #FF6666;
}
```

This occurs because `tr:nth-child(2n+1)` is more specific than `.redbg` so it overrides the background color no matter what. Changing it to `tr.redbg` makes it just as specific so the "redbg" class will override the `:nth-child()` selector.

[**See the jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/3qVxm/)

**Note for future reference:** The `tr.redbg` selector has to be defined *after* the `tr:nth-child(2n+1)` selector in order for it to override the background color.

Comment: Yeah, I just realized I was thinking about it backwards.

Comment: This does seem to work for me in Chrome, i'll accept in 6min when S.O. lets me

Answer (score 2):

It seems like that might have something to do with the rules of CSS specificity.

Try changing your selector to `tr.redbg` and see if that works.

Answer (score 2):

**Don't use** `!important` (as another answer suggests)

Instead, make your selector more specific.  Add add something like

`table tr.redbg { background-color: #FF6666; }`

Here's a [great link](http://css-tricks.com/855-specifics-on-css-specificity/) on calculating CSS specificity.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to make your redbg class more explicit than the nth child to override it.

Maybe something like (though I haven't tested it, but should get you started):

```
.redbg, tr.redbg:nth-child(2n+1)
{
background-color: #FF6666;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something about `tr:nth-child(2n+1)` taking priority because it is more specific selector.

Change the other one to

```
tr.redbg {
  background-color: #FF6666;
}
```

and it shoudl work